# BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED never called despite the bluetoothsocket is closed

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I have two devices connected through Bluetooth now. After that, I disconnected the Bluetooth connection on the Client device, and the broadcast receiver in this Client device can detect the disconnection, and then switch it back to previous activity. Something like this:

```
private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Message msg = Message.obtain();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            try {
                Log.i("Disconnecting3", "Disconectinggg....");
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(Main3Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Anyhow, on my other device which is the Server device, this device **CAN NOT** detect the disconnection despite the Bluetooth socket is closed! The broadcast receiver in the Server device cannot detect the disconnection. FYI, below code will show how I close the Bluetooth socket on the Server device when the Client device is disconnected.

```
private boolean CONTINUE_READ_WRITE;
    CONTINUE_READ_WRITE = true;
    public void run() {
            try {

                while (CONTINUE_READ_WRITE) {
                    try {
                        // Read from the InputStream.
                        numBytes = mmInStream.read(mmBuffer);
                        // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity.
                        Message readMsg = handleSeacrh.obtainMessage(MessageConstants.MESSAGE_READ, numBytes, -1, mmBuffer);
                        readMsg.sendToTarget();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        //nothing();
                        CloseConnection closeConnection = new CloseConnection();
                        closeConnection.start();
                        break;


                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Log.d(TAG, "Input stream was disconnected", e);

            }
        }

public void cancel() {
            try {
                Log.i("TAG", "Trying to close the socket");
                CONTINUE_READ_WRITE = false;
                mBluetoothSocket.close();
                mmBluetoothSocket.close();
                Log.i("TAG", "I thinked its still closing");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("TAG", "Could not close the connect socket", e);
            }
        }
```

So when there is a disconnection happened on the Client device, the while(CONTINUE_READ_WRITE)..loop will break the loop and start a new Thread. Something like this :

```
private class CloseConnection extends Thread {

    public void run(){
        Log.i("Running","Runinnggggg");

        try {
            mmInStream.close();
            mmOutStream.close();
            bluetoothDataTransmission.cancel();
            Log.i("Interrupted","InteruppteDDDD");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I found a solution , just need to add this line of code

```
intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
```